# How to change playback speed in LosslessCut?

Tags: lossless-compression, lossless

Might sound like a strange question, but hear me out. I have hours of video I want to cut up and edit together, but a lot of it is just junk I don't need. I don't want to lose any quality, so I use [LosslessCut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut).

The problem for me is that it's... A LOT of footage, and I don't need to see every single second of it. Is there a way to change playback speed in LosslessCut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change playback speed in LosslessCut. According to *Help* → *Help and shortcuts*:

- <kbd>j</kbd> Slow down playback
- <kbd>l</kbd> Speed up playback

Comment: Wow... now I feel like a dumb*ss... probably cause I am, I just didn't expect a functionality to be behind a shortcut only. Usually, you have the option to click on a button or something. Oh well, no excuses, have an upvote and the selected answer, good sir.